# What's the differance between max sanity and start sanity?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu, call-of-cthulhu-7e, sanity

I just started playing Call of Cthulhu, and decided to pick up the 7th Edition. When creating my character I got confused about the sanity numbers. Theres a max (99-Cthulhu Mythos), start (POW) and current.
My question is: can the current sanity go over the start sanity? And if so, does anything change in the character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the current sanity can go over the start sanity (equal to your POW for a new character) if you manage to gain sanity (at the end of a successful adventure for example) while not having lost too much during the investigation.

Nothing really changes for the character, it's just less likely to go insane (for the time being that is, we all know where it's going to end :) )

Note that while it's technically possible, it's not something that is supposed to happen (slipping slowly towards madness is part of the fun in CoC).

But the current sanity can never go over the max sanity (determined by your Cthulhu Mythos rating).

Comment: Are you sure that max sanity is not merely something mentioned in the book but never achieved in game? Based on my limited experience with cuthulu your max sanity is your starting sanity...

Comment: Well, if one day you manage to have a character survive long enough, it's entirely possible that you start gaining lots of Cthulhu Mythos (because that's when you get access to ancient books, deep into the campaign). The SAN loss linked to reading books is random, so it's entirely possible that at some point the max sanity will come into play. But I agree, it's rare enough that you can consider it a theoretical situation